# How to keep same number of rows to display per page

Tags: datatable, angular

I'm trying to create table with Angular2-database.
When I specify number of rows like `[mfRowsOnPage]="5"` with static number, it works fine but if I specify number of rows as variable, it works fine for first page but doesn't work after second page.

For example, if I specified `[mfRowsOnPage]="5"`, it displays 5 rows every page.

[image]

But if I specified like `[mfRowsOnPage]="numOfRows"` (numOfRows="5" or  numOfRows=5 (I tried both) is variable), the first page display 5 rows but after second page, it shows a lot more.

[image]

How can I keep 5 rows per page?

Comment: How are the rows created? Is `Angular2-database` a component? Can you provide a link to make it clear what this is about?

Comment: Looks like that's the example of the table component http://plnkr.co/edit/tINlfy?p=preview

Comment: Yes. this is from plnkr.co/edit/tINlfy?p=preview   I am talking about [mfRowsOnPage]="10" on <table>